# floor(x/y)=y graph

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was experimenting with some equations on Desmos and stumbled upon the `floor` function. I tried using it in different equations, but nothing caught my attention until I tried `y = floor(x/y)` ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDDp5.png)). This graph looks like a step function with an increasing step of 0.5, which is confusing to me. I asked MathGPT and tried to figure it out myself, but I still don't understand it. Can you please explain why this is happening?

Comment: The only points on that plot must have $y\in \mathbb Z$.  For a fixed integer $n>0$, the $x$ coordinates that work are those with $n^2≤x<n^2+1$, with something similar for $n<0$. Not sure what you mean about "recursive function".  It's certainly a step function, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Your graph can't be correct: The result of the `floor` function is always an integer, and so $y$ can only be an integer.  So the graph can have flat segments, but never any diagonals.

Comment: To answer your question about why the graph (erroneously) appears as such: the algorithm used for determining the locus of points defined by an function $F(x,y) = 0$ involves partitioning the plane into a discrete collection of points and sampling the function to deduce, via the intermediate value theorem, where the function must vanish. For this, one assumes that $F$ is piecewise smooth and continuous.

For discontinuous functions, what one ends up producing is an approximation to the boundary of the support $\operatorname s(f) = \{x \mid f(x) \neq 0\}$.

Comment: GPT generally does not "know" anything or "think" in any meaningful way. At best, it synthesizes text to look human-written & predicts what the desired words should be; it does not do real calculations ([more](https://is.gd/YRoddz)). It should not be used for math, as it will get basics wrong or "[hallucinate](https://is.gd/SUZiGn)" fake facts. Some extra examples: [1](https://bit.ly/483isiz), [2](https://bit.ly/3YRUlyX), [3](https://is.gd/WVmpdK), [4](https://bit.ly/45qeSNN), [5](https://bit.ly/44qRu1j), [6](https://is.gd/8UtFeo), [7](https://bit.ly/3KXlP0F), [8](https://bit.ly/3LpBgP4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graph is a little misleading. It only includes the "flat" parts, not the "diagonal" segments connecting them.

The complete graph is the union of the horizontal half-open segments

$$\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[n^2,n^2+n)\times\{n\}\right)\cup\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(n^2-n,n^2]\times\{-n\}\right)$$

The first union comprises segments above the x-axis, and the second comprises those below the x-axis. As you move to the right, each segment is one unit longer and one unit higher (lower, for segments below the x-axis) than the previous segment. There is a longer and longer gap between segments. Ignore the diagonal "connectors" in your graph and it is right.

Answer (score 2):

`floor(x/y)` is the integer $n$ satisfying:

$$n \le \frac{x}{y} < n + 1$$

If $n = y$, then:

$$y \le \frac{x}{y} < y + 1$$

If $y > 0$, then:

$$y^2 \le x < y^2 + y$$
$$\frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+4x}}{2} < y \le \sqrt{x}$$

If $y < 0$, then:

$$y^2 \ge x > y^2 + y$$
$$y^2 + y < x \le y^2$$
$$-\sqrt{x} \le y < \frac{-1 - \sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$$

So, you get a graph that's similar to $y = \pm \sqrt{x}$ (with both positive and negative branches), except that $y$ takes on only nonzero integer values.

Comment: Interesting approach, in connection with the approach I have in my (just posted) answer.

Answer (score 1):

(see figures below)

In such 2D questions, it is often rewarding to "take a step back" by considering curves as "level sets" (here at height $z=0$) of a surface, here with equation

$$z= y-\lfloor \tfrac{x}{y} \rfloor\tag{1}$$

The level set (intersection with plane $z=0$) gives "your" curve.
This surface is discontinuous with unbounded triangular "facets" (see Fig. 1) ; think to a spiraling  staircase with 45° inclined steps (!), each step being more narrow than the previous one...

[image]

Fig. 1 : (Matlab generated) Representation  of surface with equ. (1). The "triangular" facets of this surface aren't connected : they are separated by unit jumps, artificially "materialized" in black.

There is more to say (see Fig. 2) in the spirit of the answer by @Dan :

[image]

Fig. 2 : (Geogebra generated)  Surface with equ. (2) ($x$,$y$ axis in red and green resp.)

Indeed, the facet-surface with eq. (1) is close to the "smooth" surface with equation :

$$z=y-\frac{x}{y} \iff z=\frac{y^2-x}{y}$$

Otherwise said :
$$y^2-yz-x=0 \ \ \ (y \ne 0)\tag{2}$$

which is a quadric surface known as a "**hyperbolic paraboloid**" (sometimes said to have the shape of a horse saddle). Its name comes from the fact that its intersections with specific planes can give either parabolas (one of them is the smoothed version of "your" curve) or hyperbolas.